# Why does opacity change on hover make flex children in second row move/change?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Hey guys take a look at this example. (Look full screen) You can see the elements change opacity on hover.

However flex items that flex-wrap to the second row seem to move or change height with this same hover... It looks like a bounce effect. Nothing should be different but opacity. I tried only targeting opacity in my transition, tried flex: 0 0 23%; so links shouldn't be changing size, but still get the same result.

Basically since I've added the opacity hover/transition, second row of flex items bounce on hover.

What is going on?

```css
.nav-dropdown {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 980px;
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: #fbfbfb;
}

.nav-dropdown-image-links {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.image-link {
  flex: 0 1 23%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.image-link a {}

.image-link a img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.image-link a img:hover {
  opacity: 0.9;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-dropdown">
  <div class="nav-dropdown-image-links">
    <div class="image-link">
      <a href="https://placeholder.com">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/260x168">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="image-link">
      <a href="https://placeholder.com">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/260x168">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="image-link">
      <a href="https://placeholder.com">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/260x168">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="image-link">
      <a href="https://placeholder.com">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/260x168">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="image-link">
      <a href="https://placeholder.com">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/260x168">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="image-link">
      <a href="https://placeholder.com">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/260x168">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="image-link">
      <a href="https://placeholder.com">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/260x168">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="image-link">
      <a href="https://placeholder.com">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/260x168">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works fine in Firefox 60.0.1

Comment: You're right this does seem to be working in Firefox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following style

```
.image-link * {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

This [link](https://www.sitepoint.com/fix-chrome-animation-flash-bug/) explains why we need it.

```css
.nav-dropdown {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 980px;
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: #fbfbfb;
}

.nav-dropdown-image-links {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.image-link {
  flex: 0 1 23%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.image-link a {}

.image-link a img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.image-link a img:hover {
  opacity: 0.9;
}
.image-link * {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-dropdown">
  <div class="nav-dropdown-image-links">
    <div class="image-link">
      <a href="https://placeholder.com">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/260x168">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="image-link">
      <a href="https://placeholder.com">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/260x168">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="image-link">
      <a href="https://placeholder.com">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/260x168">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="image-link">
      <a href="https://placeholder.com">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/260x168">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="image-link">
      <a href="https://placeholder.com">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/260x168">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="image-link">
      <a href="https://placeholder.com">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/260x168">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="image-link">
      <a href="https://placeholder.com">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/260x168">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="image-link">
      <a href="https://placeholder.com">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/260x168">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow you're a goddess! I added `.image-link a img { backface-visibility: hidden; }` and that worked for me! Strange even after reading the article you linked.